# ECS task placement - does binpack and spread(instanceId) conflict?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

[image: ecs task placement]

I have a task placement strategy of

- binpack(memory)
- spread(InstanceId)

I understand that binpack(memory) tries to cram as much tasks into an instance to use as much memory as possible, while spread(InstanceId) spreads the tasks among instances.

Is the task placement strategy above then conflicting and nonsensical? Would there be some scenario where it makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, I don't see a point of your `spread` strategy. `binpack` will take precedence anyway. If you want to use `spread`, it would make more sense to `spread` across AZs first, and then use `binpack`:

```
spread(attribute:ecs.availability-zone),binpack(memory)
```

This way, ECS will first `spread` the tasks evenly across AZs for high-availability, and then use `binpack` to maximize memory usage of the instances in each AZ.

Comment: Does this spread-AZ technique *require* tasks to be in separate AZs or  attempt to do so? That is, if an ECS service requires 2 tasks and there are only two container instances with sufficient capacity in same AZ, will ECS go ahead or refuse?